# puppet 4.7 - how can I execute something at the end of a run?

Tags: puppet

I need to execute something as the very last thing of a puppet apply run. I tried to do that by defining a stage 'last', but the syntax restrictions on declaring a class in resource mode are a problem.

Is there a good way to use stages like this? Or is there some other way to make sure some class is executed last?

for example, this gives me an error for a duplicate declaration(sometimes, and I'm not sure why at this point):

```
class xyz::firstrun {

  exec { 'exec_firstrun':
    onlyif => '/usr/bin/test -e /tmp/firstrun.sh',
    command => '/tmp/firstrun.sh',
    path => ['/usr/bin/','/usr/sbin'],
    creates => '/tmp/firstrun.done',
  }

}

class { 'xyz::firstrun':
    stage => last,
}
```

Sometimes, the firstrun class runs without error, but in the main stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of run stages, but they are the the right tool for this job.  It's a bit unclear exactly what gives you the duplicate declaration error you describe, but if, for example, your class definition and class declaration both appear in the same file, then that might be a problem.

Here's how a solution using run stages might look:

### environments/production/modules/site/manifests/stages.pp

```
class site::stages {
  stage { 'last':
    # Stage['main'] does not itself need to be declared
    require => Stage['main'],
  }
}
```

### environments/production/modules/xyz/manifests/firstrun.pp

```
class xyz::firstrun {

  exec { 'exec_firstrun':
    onlyif => '/usr/bin/test -e /tmp/firstrun.sh',
    command => '/tmp/firstrun.sh',
    path => ['/usr/bin/','/usr/sbin'],
    creates => '/tmp/firstrun.done',
  }

}
```

### environments/production/manifests/nodes.pp

```
node 'foobar.my.com' {
  include 'site::stages'
  include 'something::else'

  # Must use a resource-like declaration to assign a class to a stage
  class { 'xyz::firstrun':
    stage => 'last'
  }
}
```

Note that although include-like class declarations are generally to be preferred, you must use a resource-like declaration to assign a class to a non-default stage.  You must therefore also be careful to avoid declaring such classes more than once.

Comment: i never truly understood stages because it really doesn't follow best practices (probably why you also aren't a fan), but this explanation actually makes sense to me. However, I argue for resource-like declarations myself as they allow for parameterized classes and reveal duplicate declarations.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, resource-like declarations are bad news precisely *because* they cause problems for duplicate class declaration, and secondarily because they introduce evaluation-order dependency into your manifests.  Duplicate class declarations should not be problematic because classes are singletons, and they are *not* problematic if you use resource-like class declarations.  Data should be bound to class parameters (of public classes, at any rate) via automatic data binding.

Comment: I can't really advocate data bindings for class parameters as a best practice until the Puppet Data Provider becomes production ready (which is taking FOREVER).

Comment: I will try this as @JohnBollinger suggests, because to me also stages seemed a good way to deal with my situation. I have a number of classses that can mostly run in any order, and putting dependencies everywhere just to push a class to the end seems like a extra layer of complication. to me. But from what I understand of your example, I should replace my `include xyz::firstrun` statement elsewhere with the resource declaration? Maybe that's what is causing the duplicate declaration error.

Comment: @mike.schmidt, there is no `include xyz::firstrun` statement anywhere in the code you presented in your question, so it's hard to say for sure, but in order to assign a class to a stage you must declare that class via a resource-like declaration.  If you use a resource-like declaration for a class then you can use only one, *and* it must be evaluated during catalog building before any include-like declaration of the same class.  In that case, it's best if there aren't any include-like declarations of that class.

Comment: @john bollinger true, I did not show my `include xyz::firstrun` statement in the code I presented. I never thought of it as a declaration, and when I replaced it with the resource declaration, the 'duplicate class' error went away. So I've learned that a puppet include statement is a declaration. This changes my whole view of my puppet setup. I will be testing the stages again now and comment on the result.

Comment: @mike.schmidt, in that case it might be worth your time to read the section of the Puppet language reference dealing with [class declarations](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#declaring-classes).  Who knows what other subtle but important details may have escaped your attention until now?

Comment: @john bollinger You're right. I re-read the reference on class declarations again. It's amazing how we can be so set in our definitions; I read `include` and it fit into my previous understanding of the word, and until now no amount of reading it let me see that puppet uses include in an unconventional way. If they has used some other wording I would probably have picked up on it earlier. However, I suppose, since include is allowed multiple times, include + 1 resource declaration should be allowed too. In any case, thanks for pointing that out. I will be more careful reading the puppet docs.

Comment: @mike.schmidt I don't want to pressure you or anything, but is there a reason you haven't accepted this answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [puppet relationship and ordering](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html) to do this. 
(1) If you want to execute the entire class at the end, you can include your class in init.pp and user ordering arrow (->) to execute it after all other classes.

example:

> file: /etc/puppet/modules/tomcat/init.pp

```
class tomcat {

  include ::archive
  include ::stdlib

  class { '::tomcat::tomcatapiconf': }->

  class { '::tomcat::serverconfig': }
}
```

(2) If you want a specific resource in a class to execute at the end, you can use the same arrow (->) within the class or use `before` or `require` in the resource

example:

```
file { '/etc/profile.d/settomcatparam.sh':
  ensure => file,
  before => File_line['/etc/profile.d/settomcatparam.sh'],
}

file_line { '/etc/profile.d/settomcatparam.sh':
  path => '/etc/profile.d/settomcatparam.sh',
  ine => 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usrdata/apps/sysapps/apr/lib:/usrdata/apps/sysapps/apr-util/lib:/usrdata/apps/sysapps/tomcat-native/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH',
}
```

OR

```
exec { 'configure apr-util':
  cwd     => "/tmp/apr-util-${tomcat::aprutilversion}/",
  command => "bash -c './configure --prefix=/usrdata/apps/sysapps/apr-util --with-apr=/usrdata/apps/sysapps/apr'",
} ->
exec { 'make apr-util':
  cwd     => "/tmp/apr-util-${tomcat::aprutilversion}/",
  command => 'make',
}
```

You can also use combination of `before, require and ->`. Just make sure you don't create a dependency cycle.

Comment: This isn't really a feasible approach to declaring that a given class should be applied after *all* other classes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Its a way to used ordering in puppet. What do you suggest if the requirement is once class must apply after all other?

Comment: Yes, it's a perfectly good way to define relative order of application of classes and resources.  But it's not viable for applying *universal rules* such as the OP wants to a manifest set of any appreciable size, or to a manifest set that uses third-party modules, because it requires a relationship to be set up with *every* class.  As for what I suggest, read my answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Makes sense